# spring-integration: MessageProducer may only be referenced once

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I want to use a gateway in multiple flows. My gateway definition is:

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway myServiceGateway() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("blah.*");

    MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway gateway = new MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway(
            serviceEndpoint, marshaller, messageFactory);
    gateway.setMessageSender(messageSender);
    gateway.setRequestCallback(messageCallback);

    return gateway;
}
```

Note that I have defined the message gateway bean in scope prototype so that Spring should create multiple gateway instances. Nevertheless I get this message at startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A reply MessageProducer may only be referenced once (myServiceGateway) - use @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) on @Bean definition.
```

Why does it insist that a gateway must not be referenced more than once and how can I use the same gateway from multiple flows?

Using spring-integration 5.0.4

Comment: Can you show the code that references the `myServiceGateway` bean? I just ran a test and it worked fine for me. Also add the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you have something like `.handle(myServiceGateway())` several times.

In this case you have to remove `@Bean` and `@Scope` from this method. And it also can be just `private`. The Java DSL process will create beans for you on the matter. And each flow will have its own instance. As you requested.

Any Spring Integration components can't be `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` at all. They are referenced from non-prototype beans (`endpoints`) anyway. So, essentially, the scope of your prototype beans are increased.